# Get tzoffset in seconds

Tags: python, datetime

The below code gets me the offset in hours. Is there a way to get them in seconds.

```
dt = parse('Tue Apr 26 2016 08:32:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)')    
localtz = dateutil.tz.tzlocal()
print 'offset == ',localtz.utcoffset(dt)
```

Output

```
offset ==  -1 day, 20:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

```
utc_offset = dt.utcoffset().total_seconds()
```